# Hide custom button from some Listviews

Tags: custom-button, list-view

I have a custom button which I want to show on only one ListView of Lead. Currently it is shown on all the list views. How can it be possible?

Comment: What is the criteria you want to use for basing your decision on whether you want to hide the list views? Does your organization use roles? If so, is that part of your criteria?

Comment: @crmprogdev The button should only be displayed on 'My Leads' List view. Yes, my org use roles but that has no thing to do with this button. All users will experience same UI.

Comment: So you only want it to appear on one page and the same page is re-used for all? If that's the case, you can first clone it to use as a template to provide a single page to use as the page that's displayed for "My Leads" and then remove the button on the original to use when displayed from the other links; assuming I understand your question properly.

Comment: @crmprogdev I think your solution can be implemented via visualforce pages, but I do not want to use vf pages. I am using standard salesforce listview interface. On standard listview interface I have added a button which is displayed on all Listviwes. I want it to display on only one List view.

Comment: its your choice. I know of no other way to do what you ask.